# Convergence of sequences in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, proof-verification

I am currently getting into the field of complex numbers, with the imaginary unit $i^2 = -1$ and stuff. At the moment i am looking onto a few sequences in $\mathbb{C}$, regarding convergence.

I have the feeling that $\mathbb{C}$ still is thin ice for me, so:

Can somebody please just give me a feedback weather the following proof is correct?

I want to prove

$a_n = \frac{1+i}{n+i}$ convergent. I am using the quotient criteria. Also i am using the fact that $i^2 = -1$. $0<\theta<1$

$$|\frac{\frac{1+i}{(n+1)+i}}{\frac{1+i}{n+i}}|=$$

$$|\frac{(1+i)(n+i)}{((n+1)+i)(1+i)}|=  |\frac{n+i+in-1}{(n+1)+(n+1)i +i-1}|=$$

$$|\frac{n+in+i-1}{(n+1)+in+2i-1}|<\theta$$
$$because:$$

$$n+in+i-1<n+in+2i$$

$$q.e.d.$$

If that is correct, can somebody please just give me a hint for the sequence:

$$a_n=(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})^n$$
Which criterion would you suggest looking on?

Thanks for any help.

P.S: If you are cool you can also tell me how get these || to cover the whole fraction ;) Sorry for this formatting.

Comment: `$\left| \frac{blah}{blah} \right|$` produces $\left|\frac{blah}{blah} \right|$.

Comment: A sequence $a_n = e^{\mathbb{i}na}$ converge only if $a \equiv 0\pmod{2\pi}$

Comment: Damn, i added the explanation for $\theta$ and now your suggested edit is gone cause it conflicts :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite grasp the argument you present for $\frac{1+i}{n+i}$. It looks like you're applying the ratio test, but what is the $\theta$ that appears amid all of the algebra?

It would be easier just to do
$$|a_n|=\left|\frac{1+i}{n+i}\right|=\frac{|1+i|}{|n+i|}<\frac{|1+i|}{n} \to 0 $$

For $(e^{i\pi/4})^n = e^{ni\pi/4}$ you'll need to know Euler's formula for $e^{ix}$. Compare the values for $n=0,8,16,24,\ldots$ with those for $n=4,12,20,\ldots$.

Comment: But anyway - your proof makes sense. Thanks for your help, i will review further, why my proof is wrong. I think the quotient criterion might not be applicable here.

Comment: @FalcoWinkler: But you're never saying what $\theta$ is. Note that just because you have a sequence with every $b_n<1$ it is not necessarily true that there is a $\theta<1$ such that every $b_n<\theta$ -- (for a counterexample consider $b_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$).

Comment: @FalcoWinkler: In any case, your proof definitely goes wrong when you write "$n+in+i−1<n+in+2i$" -- the "less than" relation is not defined for complex numbers.

Comment: Oh, well that is good to know! Thanks, you brought my understanding forward quite a lot.

Comment: Well, you can also just say $\left|\frac{1+i}{n+i}\right| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ for this one (but probably is it better practice to look for a upper bound sequence as OP did)

Comment: @servabat: That's what I'm appealing to here -- together with (implicitly) $\sqrt{n^2+1}>\sqrt{n^2}=n$.

Comment: @Falco: A concrete example of a _real_ sequence that would be "convergent" according to the test as you carried it out here, consider $a_n=(-1)^n(1+1/n)$. Here we have $|a_{n+1}/a_n|<1$ for all $n$, but the sequence is alternately less than $-1$ or greater than $1$, so it certainly can't converge.

Comment: Thanks again Henning. @servabat : What rule did you use there? Sorry i am a bit new to complex numbers.

Comment: @Falco: It's just $|z/w|=|z|/|w|$, combined with $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ above and below the fraction bar.

Comment: Ah yeah okay. Wow thats fancy. Complex numbers are really interesting as it seems. Thanks @everyone, i think i am good to carry on now :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm, right but I meant, just taking $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ was sufficient as it converge to $+\infty$ (without transformations). But I'm agree, and yes it's probably best practice.

Answer (score 1):

For your second sequence, the best way in my opinion is to show that :
$$\lim\left(\mathbb{e}^{ina}\right)_{n \geq0}=L, L \in \mathbb{C} \iff a \equiv 0\pmod{2\pi}.$$
($\implies$ is sufficient, but the other way is quite easy as $a \equiv 0\pmod{2\pi}$ means the sequence is a constant)